# Count duplicate words within string and remove if it occurs less than 10 times

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I've written a code to remove duplicate words in a string. However I'd like to be able to count the the occurence of words within a string and if it occurs less than 10 times I want to delete that word.

This is my code:

```
Function RemoveDupeWords(text As String, Optional delimiter As String = " ") As String

    Dim dictionary  As Object
    Dim i, part
    
    Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictionary.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    
    For Each i In Split(text, delimiter)
        part = Trim(i)
        If part <> "" And Not dictionary.Exists(part) Then
            dictionary.Add part, Nothing
        End If
    Next
    
    If dictionary.Count > 0 Then
        RemoveDupeWords = Join(dictionary.keys, delimiter)
    Else
        RemoveDupeWords = ""
    End If
    
    Set dictionary = Nothing
End Function
```

How can I do this?

I have not really tried anything, cause I dont know where to start

Comment: Do you have some sample data to go with this? Along with some desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting your dictionary value to `Nothing` use it to store a count and increment as you find more of the same word:

```
   For Each i In Split(text, delimiter)
        part = Trim(i)
        If part <> "" Then
            'if it IS NOT in the dictionary, add it. 
            If Not dictionary.Exists(part) Then
                dictionary.Add part, 1
            'if it IS in the dictionary, increment the value
            Else
                dictionary(part) = dictionary(part) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Now that you have a count for every non-blank term, you can iterate the dictionary and remove anything that meets your criteria:

```
    For Each dictKey in dictionary.keys()
        if dictionary(dictKey) < 10 Then
            dictionary.remove(dictKey)
        End If
    Next dictKey
```

Note that I haven't tested this and it's been a LONG time since I wrote VBA, but I believe the syntax is correct.

Update:

I remoted into a windows laptop and gave this a quick run and had success:

[image]

You can see that only words `a` and `test` make it through in the dictionary as expected.

Code used in test:

```
Dim dictionary  As Object
Dim i, part

Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dictionary.comparemode = vbTextCompare

For Each i In Split("this is is is is is a a a a a a a a a a a a a a test test test test test test test test test test test test of of this funcitonality", " ")
    part = Trim(i)
    If part <> "" Then
        'if it IS NOT in the dictionary, add it.
        If Not dictionary.Exists(part) Then
            dictionary.Add part, 1
        'if it IS in the dictionary, increment the value
        Else
            dictionary(part) = dictionary(part) + 1
        End If
    End If
Next

For Each dictKey In dictionary.keys()
    If dictionary(dictKey) < 10 Then
        dictionary.Remove (dictKey)
    End If
Next dictKey
```

Comment: this does not work. Nothing gets removed

Comment: You had 2 syntax errors - I have corrected them

Comment: @FunThomas Thank you! I'm using a mac right now and while VBA is supported the VBE is so slow that I just don't have the patience for it to test these things.

Comment: @user21226398 I just ran on a windows machine and had success. I added to the answer to show how this works with a working example.

Comment: @JNevill: Scripting.Dictionary doesn't work on a Mac at all as it is a windows object, not VBA

Comment: Oh! I'm glad I didn't attempt on my mac. I refuse to use VBA on this thing anyway. I just don't have the patience for it.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks, I just had to change some things so it would work on my code. But I got it to work. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer this without some sample data. I could only imagine you'd want to assert that substrings that you want to maintain are kept in their original position. You could create a function, but if you are open to using ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(del," ",MAP(A1:A4,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,TEXTSPLIT(x,del),TEXTJOIN(del,,MAP(y,LAMBDA(z,IF(SUM(--(y=z))>9,z,""))))))))
```

Comment: I don't mind if they're not in their original position. Also I will be computing some other transformation on this string so I would like the code to be in VBA

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Maybe VBA is indeed your goto, just know ms365's functions are maybe more powerfull than you think. Depending on these transformations, native functions may do just fine. At least know that there is the possibility. Also, please make sure this is not going to be an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/) =) @user21226398

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to count the number of times a substring occurs in a string you can use the function below

```
Public Function Count(byref ipHost as string, byref ipFind as string)
    Count = (len(iphost) - len(Replace(ipHost,ipFind,vbnullstring)))/len(ipFind)
end function
```